# Как сделать CSS transition для маски SVG?

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть изображение внутри встроенного SVG, которое переключается при наведении курсора между двумя масками.
Однако `CSS-transition` не работает в этом случае со свойством `transition-property: mask;`

Можно ли использовать другой метод, который работает с `transition` CSS?

Я также попробовал стилизовать `<mask>`, но получается, что элементы определения не могут быть стилизованы?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 604px; height: 302px; margin: 20px auto;"> <!-- IE needs width AND height specified to scale the SVG inside correctly. -->
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">

 <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  .mask_hover a:link,
  .mask_hover a:visited {
   mask: url(#mask_right);
  }
  .mask_hover a:hover,
  .mask_hover a:active {
   transition-property: mask;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   mask: url(#mask_left);
  }
  /* ]]> */
 </style>

 <defs>
  <mask id="mask_left">
   <circle id="circle_l" cx="416" cy="216" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
  
  <mask id="mask_right">
   <circle id="circle_r" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
  
 </defs>
 
 <g class="mask_hover">
  <a xlink:href="#">
   <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
  </a>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55174548/7394871

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле это не свойство маски, которое нельзя анимировать, а `url()` `<func>`.

Чтобы создать `transition`, вам нужно иметь `состояние 1`, которое переходит в `состояние 2` с возможностью создания интерполяции между обоими состояниями.

Когда вы используете `url(# 1)` и хотите перейти к `url(# 2)`, невозможно создать какую-либо интерполяцию между этими двумя состояниями, потому что `url(# 1.5)` не будет промежуточным состоянием.

Что может быть анимировано, так это само содержание вашей маски.

В SVG2 вы можете напрямую установить свойства, которые изменились (например, `cx` и `cy`) из CSS, но это  поддерживается только браузерами `Blink`, `Safari` и `Chrome`:

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
      mask: url(#mask);
    }
    #mask > circle {
      transition-property: cx, cy;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover + defs #mask > circle,
    .mask_hover a:active + defs #mask > circle {
      cx: 416;
      cy: 216;
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <!-- we need to move it here so we can target it with our CSS rules -->
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <circle id="circle_l" cx="809" cy="337" r="202"   fill="#fff"/>
      </mask>  
    </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Для других браузеров, которые не поддерживают эту часть SVG2, вы должны иметь возможность сделать это с помощью свойства `transform`, но  `Firefox` не принимает это ...

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
    mask: url(#mask);
    }
    #mask > circle {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover + defs #mask > circle,
    .mask_hover a:active + defs #mask > circle {
    transform: translate(-393px, -121px);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
     <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
  <!-- we need to move it here so we can target it with our CSS rules -->
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
     <circle id="circle_l" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
    </mask>  
  </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Поэтому вы также можете попробовать использовать `SMIL`, но там вы не сможете получить правило: `active`, и `Safari` будет иметь ошибки при реализации состояния наведения ...

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
      mask: url(#mask);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <circle id="circle_r" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="translate"
          to="-393 -121"
          dur="0.4s"
          fill="freeze"
          begin="anchor.mouseover"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="translate"
          to="0 0"
          dur="0.4s"
          fill="freeze"
          begin="anchor.mouseout"/>
      </circle>
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#" id="anchor">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Таким образом, последний способ может заключаться в реализации всего этого, используя только `clip-path` из CSS:

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a image {
      transition: clip-path .4s;
    }
    .mask_hover a {
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    .mask_hover a:link image,
     .mask_hover a:visited image{
      clip-path: circle(202px at 809px 337px);
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover image,
     .mask_hover a:active image{
      clip-path: circle(202px at 416px 216px);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
      <!-- so we can hover everywhre -->
      <rect fill="none" width="1208" height="604"/>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```